# BeautifulSoup only finds first element in class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** the following website: https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf

In particular, I'm trying to get all the information from 'Key Facts' and 'Portfolio Characteristics' etc. However when I run my code, it only returns the first item from each one even though there are 8-10 in each.

I feel like the loop finishes once it finds the first one, how can I get round this?

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product-data-list data-points-en_US'}):
    label = item.find(class_='caption').text
    print(label)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to grab the data from the tables and create a DataFrame:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

d = {}
for c in soup.select(".product-data-list .caption"):
    cp = c.contents[0].strip()
    dt = c.find_next(class_="data").get_text(strip=True)
    d[cp] = dt

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
         Net Assets Inception Date   Exchange Asset Class Benchmark Index Bloomberg Index Ticker Shares Outstanding Premium/Discount      CUSIP Closing Price Options Available 30 Day Avg. Volume 30 Day Median Bid/Ask Spread  Daily Volume Number of Holdings P/E Ratio P/B Ratio Equity Beta (3y) 30 Day SEC Yield Standard Deviation (3y) 12m Trailing Yield MSCI ESG Fund Rating (AAA-CCC) MSCI ESG Quality Score (0-10) MSCI ESG Quality Score - Peer Percentile MSCI ESG % Coverage Fund Lipper Global Classification MSCI Weighted Average Carbon Intensity (Tons CO2E/$M SALES) Funds in Peer Group MSCI - Controversial Weapons MSCI - UN Global Compact Violators MSCI - Nuclear Weapons MSCI - Thermal Coal MSCI - Civilian Firearms MSCI - Oil Sands MSCI - Tobacco Business Involvement Coverage Percentage of Fund not covered Management Fee Acquired Fund Fees and Expenses Foreign Taxes and Other Expenses Expense Ratio
0  $273,575,842,264   May 15, 2000  NYSE Arca      Equity   S&P 500 Index                   SPTR        662,200,000           -0.04%  464287200        412.98               Yes       4,404,180.00                        0.01%  3,052,119.00                505     31.39      4.40             1.00            1.39%                  18.40%              1.43%                            BBB                           5.5                                   48.07%              99.56%                         Equity US                                             136.45                        3,283                        0.94%                              0.69%                  0.72%               0.00%                    0.15%            0.00%          0.68%                        99.73%                          0.27%          0.03%                           0.00%                            0.00%         0.03%
```

And creates `data.csv`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its Because you are finding only one caption class.

`label = item.find(class_='caption').text`

Use the findall in caption and loop over it as well, then you will find correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Each section on the page has a specific `div` id, you can use this id to locate the specific sections:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf').text, 'html.parser')
def get_section(block):
    return [{i.select_one('span.caption').get_text(strip=True):i.select_one('span.data').get_text(strip=True),
            'As Of':i.select_one('span.as-of-date').get_text(strip=True)} 
              for i in block.select('div.product-data-list div.float-left')]

results = {'Key Facts':get_section(d.select_one('#w1467271812603')), 'Portfolio Characteristics':get_section(d.select_one('#w1467271812604'))}
```

Output:

```
{'Key Facts': [{'Net Assetsas of Apr 09, 2021': '$273,575,842,264', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'Inception Date': 'May 15, 2000', 'As Of': ''}, {'Exchange': 'NYSE Arca', 'As Of': ''}, {'Asset Class': 'Equity', 'As Of': ''}, {'Benchmark Index': 'S&P 500 Index', 'As Of': ''}, {'Bloomberg Index Ticker': 'SPTR', 'As Of': ''}, {'Shares Outstandingas of Apr 09, 2021': '662,200,000', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'Premium/Discountas of Apr 09, 2021': '-0.04%', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'CUSIP': '464287200', 'As Of': ''}, {'Closing Priceas of Apr 09, 2021': '412.98', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'Options Available': 'Yes', 'As Of': ''}, {'30 Day Avg. Volumeas of Apr 09, 2021': '4,404,180.00', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'30 Day Median Bid/Ask Spreadas of Apr 09, 2021': '0.01%', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'Daily Volumeas of Apr 09, 2021': '3,052,119.00', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}], 
'Portfolio Characteristics': [{'Number of Holdingsas of Apr 09, 2021': '505', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'P/E Ratioas of Apr 09, 2021': '31.39', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'P/B Ratioas of Apr 09, 2021': '4.40', 'As Of': 'as of Apr 09, 2021'}, {'Equity Beta (3y)as of Mar 31, 2021': '1.00', 'As Of': 'as of Mar 31, 2021'}, {'30 Day SEC Yieldas of Mar 31, 2021': '1.39%', 'As Of': 'as of Mar 31, 2021'}, {'Standard Deviation (3y)as of Mar 31, 2021': '18.40%', 'As Of': 'as of Mar 31, 2021'}, {'12m Trailing Yieldas of Mar 31, 2021': '1.43%', 'As Of': 'as of Mar 31, 2021'}]}
```